# Is YYYY-W10-7 Always the second Sunday in March?

Tags: iso8601

We have an application that needs to know about specific dates and times that trigger DST start and end dates.  For example in the US DST starts on the first Sunday in March.

Is the second Sunday in March always YYYY-W10-7?  Spot checking years seems to bear this out, but I'd be much more comfortable with a formal proof.

Comment: Just out of curiousity, what platform are you targetting?

Comment: Ah. Guessing you knew about the `TimeZoneInfo` class in .net 3.5, but obviously that's no good for Linux.

Comment: There are only 14 cases to check: the first day of the year is {Sunday,Monday,Tuesday,Wednesday,Thursday,Friday,Saturday} and February has {28,29} days.

Comment: Using [this](http://vpcalendar.net/Year_Correlations.html) as a source, if you check for the years 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2012, 2016, 2020, 2024, and 2028 you've checked every calendar.

Answer (score 0):

The second Sunday in March has a range of 3/8 (if Sunday was 3/1) to 3/14 (if Saturday was 3/1).

If the second Sunday in March is 3/8 (the earliest possible date) and the year is not a leap year, then January 1 is a Thursday, making the first week of the year eligible for W01.  Counting up from January 1 to March 8, and March 8 then occurs W11-7.  This occurred (and therefore can be manually spot checked) in 2009.

If the second Sunday is March is 3/14 (the latest possible date) and the year is not a leap year, then January 1 is a Friday, making that week ineligible for W01, and W01 starts on January 4.  Counting up from January 4 to March 14, and March 14 then occurs W10-7.  This occurred (and therefore can be manually spot checked) in 2010.

So, unfortunately, there doesn't appear to be a way to specify DST start and end dates in ISO 8601 in a standard way without revisiting the calculation each year.

Comment: The dates would be more useful internationally if you put them into an unambiguous format. To most people outside of the US, those dates simply hurt.